# Java Google Sheets API OAuth 2.0

Tags: java, google-api, google-oauth

I'm having problems setting up my program to make calls to the Google Sheets API. Currently, I'm authorizing my credential this way:

```
public static Credential authorize() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    InputStream p12 = GoogleUtils.class.getResourceAsStream("/key.p12");

    File file = new File("hi");
    OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    IOUtils.copy(p12, outputStream);
    outputStream.close();

    // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
   GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
        .setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT)
        .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
        .setServiceAccountId("8429209348-1nfuorcfko5pmqh2l0b1au968igchaoq@developer.gserviceaccount.com")
        .setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPES)
        .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(file)
        .build();
    return credential;
}
```

But, I don't know what to do with this credential now that I have it. In another class, I'm opening up a `SpreadsheetService`, but I can't find the method to actually authorize with the `Credential` object. I remember doing this in one of my older projects:

```
public GoogleDrive() {
    /** Our view of Google Spreadsheets as an authenticated Google user. */
    try {
        InputStream p12 = BotPanel.class.getResourceAsStream("/key.p12");

        File file = new File("hi");
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        IOUtils.copy(p12, outputStream);
        outputStream.close();

        String emailAddress = "81607255786-225dt8i2s8q6qgi0lgg814p27mumqro2@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
        HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
        JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
        String[] SCOPESArray = { "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds", "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full", "https://docs.google.com/feeds" };
        final List<String> SCOPES = Arrays.asList(SCOPESArray);
        GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                    .setTransport(httpTransport).setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
                    .setServiceAccountId(emailAddress).setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPES)
                    .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(file)
                    .build();

        file.delete();
        service = new SpreadsheetService("Test");
        service.setOAuth2Credentials(credential);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

As you can see I get the `Credential` the same way, and at the end I'm able to just call `service.setOAuth2Credentials(credential);`But in my newer project, this is what I'm getting:

[image]

As you can see there isn't a method called `.setOAuth2Credential(...)` anymore.

Digging into the src code, I found the method in the `GoogleService` class, only it had the annotation @Beta.

```
@Beta
  public void setOAuth2Credentials(Credential credential) {
    GoogleAuthTokenFactory googleAuthTokenFactory = getGoogleAuthTokenFactory();
    googleAuthTokenFactory.setOAuth2Credentials(credential);
    requestFactory.setAuthToken(authTokenFactory.getAuthToken());
  }
```

Is there a reason why this code is annotated with @Beta? Is there some other way I'm supposed to authorize calls to the sheets api? Or is there some way to still authorize with this method? (that would be ideal).

Answer (score 0):

The answer was simple. I had the wrong dependencies the whole time. Make sure that you have gdata-client version 1.47. Here's a link to the jar file http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.gdata/core/1.47.1. Once I used that as a library all my problems went away :)

Answer (score 0):

There's an updated quickstart guide for this:

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/java

The tldr; version is:

1. set up the desktop app in Google Cloud console (set up the app, authorize credentials, create new credentials.json)
2. set up the project, hook up the credentials.json (working code example in the link)
3. run the project and you should already be able to at least read from a specific spreadsheet/sheet

The quickstart guide helped me get started, but there was a lot to learn when I wanted to wipe sheets, add values, add conditional formatting or alternating row colors and such. You can follow the next steps in the guide to see the rest of what the API can do. It was a great fun to mess with it as the results can be seen immediatelly 'cause the sheets update automatically.

When it comes to dependencies, the current set of dependencies you need is:

Gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:2.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.34.1'
implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-sheets:v4-rev20220927-2.0.0'
```

Maven:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
        <version>1.34.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-sheets</artifactId>
        <version>v4-rev20220927-2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```